# The static library are included, but still link to dynamic library in same name at runtime

Tags: gcc, cuda, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I am using nvcodec sdk (https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) and use its linux static library in my project.

I added the compile option in gcc with

```
gcc myprogram.c  NvCodec/Lib/linux/stubs/x86_64/libnvcuvid.so
```

However, when running the program,

```
./bin/a.out: symbol lookup error: ./bin/a.out: undefined symbol: cuvidGetDecodeStatus
```

I found that the symbol cuvidGetDecodeStatus is actually in NvCodec/Lib/linux/stubs/x86_64/libnvcuvid.so.

And by

```
nm a.out
```

the symbol is included in the program.

so I tried

```
ldd a.out
```

I found it's linked to nvidia driver with same name.

```
libnvcuvid.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libnvcuvid.so.1
```

I can't modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to modify the search order since NvCodec is a static library.

I have no idea why it's linked to the nvidia driver library even I don't add link option (like -lnvcuvid)

And idea?

thank you

Comment: in what way is `libnvcuvid.so` a static library?  Read [this page](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) that you linked carefully.  What is the driver version requirement listed on that page? (hint: 396.xx)  What driver version do you have installed? (appears to be 384.xx)

Comment: I tried ldd NvCodec/Lib/linux/stubs/x86_64/libnvcuvid.so, and ldd said that it's a static library.

Comment: it's a stub library, used as a placeholder for the real libnvcuvid.so The real libnvcuvid.so (provided by the GPU driver) is a dynamic library.

Comment: ok. I will tried to update the driver. I have no idea about stub library. Can you explain more?

Comment: when running `ldd NvCodec/Lib/linux/stubs/x86_64/libnvcuvid.so`, it outputs   `statically linked`, does not it mean it's a static library?

Comment: That means it has no dynamic link dependencies.  It does not mean that it is a statically-linkable library.

Comment: ok. then How to find out it's a stub library?

Comment: The fact that it is in a directory tree with `stubs` is certainly a clue.  Anyway this is all besides the point, I suspect.  Your link operation was probably successful (albeit dynamic), and the issue you are facing is because you are trying to use a linked executable that expects a 396.xx driver and you are running a 384.xx driver.  That is my guess anyway.  I would sort that out first.

Comment: if it's a driver issue, then it seems that the lookup symbol is in the 396.xx version, not in 384.xx.

Comment: I will try to update the driver version and come back here. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Robert Crovella said,

this is an issue for an outdated driver. the library in the cuda codec sdk is actually a stub, which points to the cuda driver shared library.

And there is no symbol like cuvidGetDecodeStatus in the nvidia-384 driver library.

after update nvidia-384 to nvidia-396, the problem solved.